# Spring Boot 3 + OAuth2 + Keycloak invalid session ID

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, keycloak

I am implementing Keycloak 22.0.5 with OAuth2 and Spring Boot 3.1.5. I want to use Basic Authentication. On the keycloak side I have created a Realm, client, user and the appropriate roles for the user and that are applicable to the endpoint I am pinging.
I have the problem that I constantly get this error:

```
DEBUG o.s.s.w.s.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter - Request requested invalid session id ***SESSION_ID_TOKEN***
```

The SESSION_ID_TOKEN is always the same in the logs on each request I try to send to the endpoint and I always get 401 Unauthorized.

This is the current implementation that I have:

*application.yml:*

```
origins: http://localhost:9999
issuer: **KEYCLOAK-URL**

com:
  c4-soft:
    springaddons:
      oidc:
        ops:
          - iss: ${issuer}
            username-claim: preferred_username
            authorities:
              - path: $.realm_access.roles
                prefix: ROLE_
              - path: $.resource_access.*.roles
        resourceserver:
          cors:
            - path: /**
              allowed-origin-patterns: ${origins}
          permit-all:
            - "/example"
```

*WebSecurityConfig:*

```
@Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(accessManagement -> accessManagement
                .anyRequest().authenticated());
        http.sessionManagement(sm -> sm.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));
        http.exceptionHandling(eh -> eh.authenticationEntryPoint((request, response, authException) -> {
            response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.WWW_AUTHENTICATE, "Bearer realm=\"Restricted Content\"");
            response.sendError(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value(), HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.getReasonPhrase());
        }));
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

The settings that I have in Keycloak -> Realm settings -> Sessions are these:
[image][image]

Anybody have any idea where the issue might be?

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few inconsistencies in your question:

- what's the point of setting up Keycloak for `Basic` authentication? Keycloak is an OIDC authorization server, it is intended to be used in OAuth2 security flows
- you use [`spring-addons-starter-oidc`](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons#1-spring-boot-starter) properties, so I imagine you have [the jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/c4-soft/springaddons/spring-addons-starter-oidc/) on the classpath (can't be sure as you provide neither pom nor gradle build files), but you define your own `SecurityFilterChain` without a `securityMatcher` => this filter chain is intended to process all requests. What's the point to use spring-addons if the `resourceServerSecurityFilterChain` it configures is never used?
- the `SecurityFilterChain` you defined is stateless, but is configured neither for `Basic` nor `Bearer` authorizations. How do you expect it to work exactly?

My guess is because you haven't set `Basic` or `Bearer` authorization in the `SecurityFilterChain` you defined (and designed to intercept all requests), Spring Security tries to build a security context from a session, but as you also defined `sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)`, it can't find a valid session token. But without a reproducer project, it is hard to tell.